# How do I run python on my Vagrant vm instance that is CoreOS?

Tags: vagrant, coreos

How do I run python on my Vagrant vm instance that is CoreOS? I would like to access the python interpreter. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can also install `python` on CoreOS using the below script, let's call it `install_python.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

PYPY_VERSION=5.10.1

wget -O - https://bitbucket.org/pypy/pypy/downloads/pypy3-v$PYPY_VERSION-linux64.tar.bz2 |tar -xjf -
mv -n pypy3-v$PYPY_VERSION-linux64 pypy

## library fixup
mkdir -p pypy/lib
if [[ -f /lib64/libncurses.so.5.9 ]]; then
        libncurses_version=5.9
else
        libncurses_version=6
fi

ln -snf /lib64/libncurses.so.$libncurses_version $HOME/pypy/lib/libtinfo.so.5

mkdir -p $HOME/bin

cat > $HOME/bin/python <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/pypy/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH exec $HOME/pypy/bin/pypy3 "\$@"
EOF

chmod +x $HOME/bin/python
$HOME/bin/python --version
```

You can add it as a provision script to your `Vagrantfile`:

```
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.provision "shell", path: "install_python.sh"
end
```

install python for `core` user or `root` user and use python interpreter using `/home/core/bin/python` for example:

```
$ /home/core/bin/python --version
Python 3.5.3 (3f6eaa010fce, Jan 11 2018, 04:44:35)
[PyPy 5.10.1 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901]

$ /home/core/bin/python          
Python 3.5.3 (3f6eaa010fce, Jan 11 2018, 04:44:35)
[PyPy 5.10.1 with GCC 6.2.0 20160901] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>>>
```

Comment: @MaxLobur thank you. That's right. There is no `libncurses.so.5.9` anymore in CoreOS 1911.x.x. I've updated script to support CoreOS with mentioned version.

Answer (score 0):

Applications and dependencies such as python run in containers on CoreOS. There are many pre-built python containers, such as: https://quay.io/repository/freshbooks/python