# How to install Python on CoreOS under core user?

Tags: python, coreos

Follow this guide to try to install Python on CoreOS:

https://github.com/judexzhu/Install-Python-on-CoreOs

```
#!/bin/bash -uxe

VERSION=2.7.13.2715
PACKAGE=ActivePython-${VERSION}-linux-x86_64-glibc-2.12-402695

# make directory
mkdir -p /opt/bin
cd /opt

wget http://downloads.activestate.com/ActivePython/releases/${VERSION}/${PACKAGE}.tar.gz
tar -xzvf ${PACKAGE}.tar.gz

mv ${PACKAGE} apy && cd apy && ./install.sh -I /opt/python/

ln -sf /opt/python/bin/easy_install /opt/bin/easy_install
ln -sf /opt/python/bin/pip /opt/bin/pip
ln -sf /opt/python/bin/python /opt/bin/python
ln -sf /opt/python/bin/python /opt/bin/python2
ln -sf /opt/python/bin/virtualenv /opt/bin/virtualenv
```

The script works well under root user on CoreOS. But under `core` user it can't work.

If use this:

```
cat > ~/.bashrc << EOF
export PATH=\$PATH:/opt/bin
EOF
```

Shows `-bash: /home/core/.bashrc: Read-only file system`.

How how to do?

Comment: Please have a look here - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816491/how-do-i-run-python-on-my-vagrant-vm-instance-that-is-coreos/48338831#48338831

Comment: @Nickolay Thank you. I can install Python that way but also can't add `/home/core/bin/python` to `~/.bashrc` file since `-bash: /home/core/.bashrc: Read-only file system`.