# How to run Python with docker on daemon mode?

Tags: python, docker, process, ansible, coreos

Get python from Docker Hub:

```
$ docker pull python
```

on CoreOS.

Want to use Ansible to connect it from other host, so it's necessary to launch Python on CoreOS.

But how to do by this way?

---

## More details

This way can run ansible with coreos:

### Step 1: Install python with shell script on CoreOS

(It's said not good but now it can be used)

[How do I run python on my Vagrant vm instance that is CoreOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36816491/how-do-i-run-python-on-my-vagrant-vm-instance-that-is-coreos/48338831#48338831)

### Step 2: Config hosts in an ansible-playbook

```
[coreos]
core-01

[coreos:vars]
ansible_ssh_user=core
ansible_python_interpreter=/home/core/bin/python
```

### Step 3: Test connection

```
$ ansible -m ping -u core -i hosts core-01
core-01 | SUCCESS => {
    "changed": false,
    "ping": "pong"
}
```

It can be used. But about `Step 1`, is there a way to use python container to launch it instead of using shell script to install?

Comment: I'm confused as to what your asking, just how to run a docker container?

Comment: Ansible is used for installing all the packages required for infrastructure i.e Java 8 or python 3.6 etc.You cannot do with docker pull.Docker pull is used for pulling the images from Docker Hub or Docker repo.Ansible will take part in installing python definitely.

Comment: @chrisz How to run python as a container that other host can know its python process.

Comment: @Ankur I added some details in the question.

Comment: Inside vagrant you can set up virtual environment like set virtualenv . Then you can install python inside that, thats what we did 2-3 years back when we were using vagrant to set up python Django project.

Comment: @Ankur `virtualenv` depends on python.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even you are able to connect to the python container via ansible, the python code will be executing inside the container. So there is no practical use for it unless you really want to do something inside the container using ansible.

The best way to install python in coreos is using ansible's `raw` module.

Ref:

1). https://coreos.com/blog/managing-coreos-with-ansible.html
2). http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/raw_module.html